# python3, web scraping, beautifulsoup can't return data

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i have been trying for two days to extract the price of BTC from https://www.bitfinex.com/stats. I am missing something fundamental as i have looked at lots of different tutorials, videos and blogs.

the price is located in the HTML like this -

```
<td class="col-currency">4849.7</td>
```

my code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#enter website address
url = requests.get('https://www.bitfinex.com/stats')
html = url.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

where do i go from here?

Comment: Do you mean, perhaps, 'BTC USD LAST TRADE'?

Comment: Try this, 
a = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "col-currency"})
for i in a:
   print i.get_text(strip=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the bs4 documentation
You're looking for this to find the element

```
data = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'col-currency'})
```

then this to get the text

```
data = data.text
```

if data.text doesn't work, you can just use string manipulation to get the result from data

Comment: i did it like this 
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    now = datetime.now()
    #enter website address
    url = requests.get('https://www.bitfinex.com/stats')
    #html = url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html.parser')
    #create price var and search html for tags attached to price
    price = (soup.find("td", "col-currency"))
    #convert into floating point decimal and strip tags
    price = (float(price.get_text()))

    print(price)